Is reading "Journey To The West" Avodah Zarah?
So I'm considering reading the famous Chinese novel Journey To The West, which is about a Buddhist monk, and entails interactions with Taoists and Confucians. From my understanding this book is considered a great novel in world history, and is read throughout China and Japan. Does someone violate Jewish laws of Avodah Zarah by reading this book?
Backdrop: interest in this book has picked up since a famous video game based on it came out and it's also the basis for Dragon Ball.
Edit: so YesChat.ai's Rabbi GPT-Orthodox Jewish Law AI says:
""Journey to the West," a classic Chinese novel, is primarily a fantasy-adventure story based on the pilgrimage of a Buddhist monk to retrieve sacred texts. It involves numerous mythological figures, including gods and demons, many of whom are drawn from Buddhist and Taoist traditions. This does raise questions about avodah zara (idol worship) because the novel includes depictions of deities and practices that are associated with foreign religions.
When considering if reading such a book is avodah zara, we can approach the issue from a halachic perspective:
Actual Worship vs. Study: Avodah zara generally refers to the actual worship or participation in forbidden practices. Simply reading about non-Jewish religious ideas or mythologies does not necessarily fall under this prohibition, especially if the intent is not to engage in those practices. Many poskim allow the study of such material for academic or literary purposes as long as it doesn't lead to admiration or respect for the foreign gods or practices described (Shulchan Aruch, Yoreh De'ah 147:2).

The Concern of Influence: However, there is a concern about exposure to ideas that could influence one’s emunah (faith) or lead to improper thoughts. The Rambam in Hilchos Avodah Zarah (2:2) emphasizes distancing oneself from foreign religious ideologies, which could affect one's spiritual purity.

Entertainment Value: If someone is reading the book purely for its entertainment value, without taking the religious elements seriously, it may be more lenient. But still, it's recommended to have a level of caution regarding materials that openly promote or depict avodah zara, even in a fictionalized format.

In conclusion, while reading Journey to the West isn't technically avodah zara if read for academic or literary purposes, it's important to be mindful of the content and how it might affect one’s beliefs. It’s advisable to consult with a local Rav for a more personalized psak, especially if one feels that the material might be spiritually compromising."

Dragonball is only loosely based on it

Thought for a split second that we were talking about a Babylonian sage travelling to the Holy Land...

Shulchan Aruch Orach Chaim 307:16 (translation mine, with my own comments in italics):

It is forbidden to read stories, parables regarding secular matters,
love stories like the Book of Emanuel, books of wars (possibly he
means adventure stories) on Shabbat.  And it is even forbidden to
read them on weekdays, because of the concept of moshav leitzim
(literally, a gathering place of scoffers--by spending your time on
these things, you show a lack of regard for important matters like
Torah study).  One who reads them also transgresses the verse of "Do
not turn towards the non-gods," meaning "do not turn towards that
which teaches of them."  Love stories are additionally prohibited
because they incite lust.  The authors of such works, their editors,
and certainly their publishers are all guilty of causing the public to
sin.

Mishna Brura, sub-paragraph 59:

Because of the concept of moshav leitzim.  And how much more so is it
forbidden to go to theaters or circuses for this reason, or to other
entertainments.  And even on Purim, the only entertainment which is
permitted is that which is done to remember the miracles of
Achashverosh (that is, Purim plays which recount the miraculous
events that occurred in the times of Achashverosh).  In our many
sins, nowadays many people treat this prohibition very lightly, freely
attending the theater.  Scripture screams about this, saying 'Israel,
do not rejoice in the entertainments of the nations!'  It also incites
the Evil Inclination.  Chazal said that one who does such things will
'fall into Gehennom...and also he will suffer (in This World), as it
says 'Do not be leitzim, lest your suffering increase.'

So I don't know if it's specifically a violation of the laws of Avodah Zarah, but it seems clear to me that it is not permitted.

The Rema also says it would be mutar if it were in Lashon HaKodesh and also “nahagu lahakel.” I don’t know if that refers to a kula by Lashon HaKodesh novels or by the whole sugya.

@Shimshon  True.  I left that Rema out for two reasons. First, because it seems very unlikely that OP was talking about a story written in Lashon HaKodesh (or even in modern Hebrew, which is in any event not the same thing), and also because he limits the leniency to "secular matters and war stories.  Second, Rema only says this leniency about "sichas chulin v'sipurei milchamos," "secular mattes and war/adventure stories," things which are unobjectionable in themselves, but are time wasters.  About them there is possibly a logic that it is permitted if you're improving your mastery of (next)

@Shimshon (continued) Lashon HaKodesh.  But common sense dictates, and the Mishna Berurah affirms (sub-paragraph 62) that Rema would agree that inherently objectionable material, like love stories and things that teach heretical or idolatrous ideas, are forbidden in any language.  So the cases where the Rema's leniency is available as a practical matter are few and far between!

I’m happy to accept that the following argument is wrong out of respect for the heilige Mishnah Berurah, but I want to know the proper teretz: Scripture screams “do not enjoy the entertainment of the nations,” but nowadays a vast percentage of US popular entertainment involves the active participation and coordination of Jews and Jewish-controlled production. Take, for example, not just Spielberg but television shows like “Shtisel” and “Fauda.” How would the Shulchan Aruch or Mishnah Berurah account for this? How do you know the parameters of the Rama’s “nahagu lehakel”?

Also, does modern Hebrew qualify as Lashon HaKodesh with regard to the kula of the Rama? What if a story has an element of war, as well as elements of love,  like “Fauda” or The Caine Mutiny by Herman Wouk? What is the geder for “heretical or idolatrous ideas”? How do you determine, l’chatchilah, whether a story contains such elements? How do we know this applies to all forms of popular entertainment, since our mekoros refer only to books? Can we compare this to the apparently-inconclusive debate as to the issur of non-liturgical music?

@Shimshon  It seems to me that the point of these halachos is not "You should not consume entertainment created by people of other-than-Jewish ethnic background," but "You should not waste your time, and also you should not import into your mind images and attitudes and ideas which the Torah forbids."  Obviously, I never met the Chofetz Chaim personally, neither me nor my father nor my grandfather.  But it seems to me that if he were here with us today, he would weep bitterly when told that nowadays Jews not only consume such stuff, but play a huge role in creating it.

@Shimshon   The question about whether modern Hebrew qualifies as Lashon HaKodesh for this purpose should be taken to a posek.  Certainly I do not know.  However, even if it does, at best that only takes away the "time waster" stigma from a particular novel or entertainment vehicle.  If it contains pritzus, apikorsus, leitzonus, lashon hara, etc, that's a separate issue, and being in Lashon HaKodesh does not help.  And, correct me if I'm wrong, but basically all mainstream entertainment created today is full of that stuff.  Especially pritzus.

@Shimshon  As for making a determination l'chatchila, it's definitely a chicken and egg problem.  You can't decide until you view it, but you cannot view it until you have decided it's mutar to view it!   I think that the only solution here is to err on the side of caution, and assume that anything created by a person who is not known to be full of Torah and yiras shomayim is off-limits.

@Shimshon  The system is now warning me that this conversation is really getting too long for comments.  Can we move to chat, or perhaps to email?  My address is yehoshua.kahan@gmail.com

The context of the halachot above is not to focus on divrei chol during Shabbat and the additional issue of bitul Torah. But what is someone will in any case read a secular book. The question remains whether books focused on non-idolatrous religions transgress the laws of avoda zara

The Shulchan Aruch specifies that this seif is dealing with material which is forbidden on weekdays as well as on Shabbos.   @mbloch

@YehoshuaKahan right but as you know it is in Hilchot Shabbat

@YehoshuaKahan thank you for the contact and gut voch

@mbloch that’s an interesting point—as if to suggest that a secular book is divrei chol and only usur b’shem hilchos Shabbat

mbloch and @Shimson, sure it's in hilchos Shabbos.  That doesn't change the fact that Shulchan Aruch specifies that these materials are assur all the time.  Which makes sense, as it is never mutar to be mevatel Torah, or to import pritzus, leitzanus, apikorsus, etc. into one's  head.  It's in Hilchos Shabbat because there are a variety of things which are assur to read only on Shabbos, like commercial contracts.  He has a lengthy discussion here of things that are assur to read on Shabbos.  And he also includes this seif which explicitly applies on Shabbos and weekday alike.
